# Android videoview scroll the listview to next page in fragment when I change the orientation

Tags: android

I have 4 full screen video in my `ListView`. I am using fragments to show that because I am also using `ViewPager` to swipe the pages. The scenario of view hierarchy is like this

ViewPager->ListView->RelativeLayout->VideoView

My problem is that when I load the view at first time it's coming all fine but when I change the orientation of my device than it scroll the listview for the next half item which is also the videoview.

It's happening only when I add the videoview in my listview it I didnt add or try to add some other views instead of videoview than it's working all fine.

Please help to solve my problem because this is the part where I am relally stuked from lat 2 days. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your VideoView try to setFocusable(false), work out it with focus, when device orientation changes, ListView tries to scroll to focused items, it depends sometimes on phone too.

Comment: thank you very much now it's working all fine by adding setFocusable(false).